# Flow Builder - Lookup Input Component No Records Returned

Tags: visual-workflow, lookup, user

I am trying to use the lookup input component in a flow to find a user record by email.

Lookup component setup screenshot below where `EmailAPIName = Email` and `UserAPINameConst = User` and are both of the data type Constant.

[image]

No records are showing up and under the lookup it's displaying the following message under the lookup:

> 'Select an option or remove the search term'

I can pull up user records in dev console through SOQL with no problem:

```
select id from user where email = 'myEmail@myCompany.com'
```

**Activated Flow with Lookup field:**

[image]

The flow is being displayed on a lightning community page and as an admin of the community page, I not seeing any results on the flow.

What gives?

Comment: Have you tried using this Flow in an internal (non-Communities) context?  Wondering if this could be an issue of user visibility specifically within Communities.  Check this article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_community_user_visibility.htm&type=5

Comment: Same issue with lookup on lightning page within Service Console as well.

Comment: Tried it with a case object and subject field as well, inside and outside of communities same results.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you’re trying to do with this component? Do you want to search for a user by email address? I don’t think this component does what you expect it to, but there might be another we can recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup field must actually be a field of lookup type.

To query for a user object for example, on the lookup component you could select an Object API Name of value `"Case"` and Field API Name of value `"CreatedById"` and this appears to perform a SOSL lookup of all fields on the User Object since CreatedById is of field type: `Lookup(User)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the lookup component was case sensitive on the object and field API name:

[image: Lookup component deatil]